# Is querying by index using c++ vector faster than querying by key(index) in RocksDB or LevelDB?

Tags: c++, vector, leveldb, rocksdb

I am thinking of using RocksDB or LevelDB to store my data persistently for my face recognition software. Right now, I am using a c++ vector and it is not persistent, which means everytime I restart my software I have to reload data into my vector. My data is has about 1 million elements, each being a vector of 512 floats. Query speed is of upmost concern and ideally I need o(1) query speed when I query with an index. From my research, I can't really find such guarantee for RocksDB and LevelDB.

My question is is it worth investing my effort into using RocksDB or LevelDB or are they slower than vector?

Comment: The only answer is: benchmark.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I am just asking if rocks and level are always slower or will there be cases when they are faster? If they are always slower, there is no point benchmarking.

Comment: Slower that *what*? In-memory direct access? Yes. Than managing your own files and index? Maybe. Than a general SQL database? Probably not. For something to be "slower" you need something to compare to. That's why you do the benchmarking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wrote vector (c++ stl vector)

Comment: So you have a vector of vectors? How do you find the correct sub-vector? Do you have an index of indexes into the vector? Then that's as fast as you're going to get. If you have the memory to store all data in memory, then just some simple serialization of the vector and index is all you need. Load at startup, save on shutdown (or on change).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the question about index structure is "no." RocksDB and LevelDB use a tree structure for their indexes (a log-structured merge tree, to be precise), which translates to O(log N) queries.

Given that you have a fixed number of fixed-size elements, you can pretty easily get O(1) "querying" on your own though.

Just store your data in a binary file. You can seek to the appropriate point using `istream::seekg`, then read the 512 floats using `istream::read`.

```
struct record { 
    float data[512];
};

std::istream &read_record(istream &is, size_t record_number, record &r) {
    auto read_start = record_number * sizeof(r);
    is.seekg(read_start);
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(r), sizeof(r));
}
```

It may, however, be open to question whether this actually provides a performance improvement. In particular, given only a million elements, a binary tree would only have a depth of about 20. A multiway tree will be even shallower. For this small a size, chances are that the entire index will be in memory all the time, and searching a small tree in memory is *very* fast compared to even the most trivial disk I/O. Searching the index is unlikely to affect the read speed by a significant amount.

At the same time, it's unlikely that using a DB will be any easier to write than code like above, and there's virtually no chance that it'll be any faster either (though it is *possible* that it could, for example, provide more effective caching than your OS, so that it would be faster under some circumstances).